# Microsoft Identity - how to check access token validity and prevent MsalUiRequiredException

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, blazor-server-side, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a Blazor Server app that calls downstream api (Sharepoint Online API) on behalf of logged in user.

However, users are sometimes getting `MsalUiRequiredException`. I understand that's because the token became invalid.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                   
   .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
   .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(sharepointScopes)
   .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

ClientContext SharepointClientFactory()
{
   var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

   clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
   {
       try
       {
           string accessToken = _tokenAcquisition
                           .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes: effectiveScopes, authenticationScheme: OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                           .GetAwaiter()
                           .GetResult();

           e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
       }
       catch (MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException ex)
       {
           //_consentHandler.HandleException(ex); I want prevent this from happening in advance
       }
   };
}
```

Simple page refresh does not help here, because the authentication cookie is still valid.

1. How do I check the access token validity before the app is shown to the user? (e.g. when user visits _host.cshtml which hosts the blazor app)?
2. Is there any other way to prevent access token expiration during user session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to check access token validity

```js
public async Task<bool> IsAccessTokenValid()
{
    try
    {
        string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes: effectiveScopes, authenticationScheme: OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return true;
    }
    catch (MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException ex)
    {
        // Access token is invalid
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: or theck this   https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/validate-access-tokens/go/main/